# Scale an image without filling screen

Tags: wpf, fullscreen, scale, image-viewer

I did a simple imageviewer and when I scale an image it takes the whole screen. I want it to get bigger but inside its grid.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information here, normally just putting an `Image` control into the `Grid` should do as it stretches to its bounds.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="..."/>
<Grid/>
```

Comment: So you will want to resize the grid, not the image

Comment: I have an image and right next to it i have textbox, and when I scale the image it covers the textbox. I want it to be scaled but stay in its grid.